# Whole-pixel alignment of font character (glyphicon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap uses icons from a font file. If the icon is displayed in an element which is positioned off-pixel (caused eg. by setting the parent to percentage width like 51% and floating the icon right), it is blurred.

Here is code which has manually set position as 40.3px to demonstrate the effect:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" 
    style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 20px; font-size: 12px;"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"
    style="position: absolute; left: 40.3px; top: 40.3px; font-size: 12px;"></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s24howr2/

You will notice that the second icon is a little bit blurred. Many people do not even see it, but it's a problem. If you align an image this way, it renders properly.

Is there any CSS rule I could use to force the glyphicon (or a font in general) to always align on rounded pixel?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should try using some font-smoothing.

**-webkit-font-smoothing: [ auto | initial | none | antialiased | subpixel-antialiased ]**

This property only works with webkit browsers, like Safari and Chrome. See http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing for more on this.

**font-smooth: [ auto | never | always |  |  ]**

This is part of the W3C's CSS Font module specification. You can view the whole thing at http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop .